# cost of implementing pipeline operator

Tags: f#

I'm following a language called 'elm' which is an attempt to bring a Haskel-esque syntax and FRP to Javascript.  There has been some discussion here about implementing the pipeline operator from F# but the language designer has concerns about the increased cost (I assume in increased compilation time or compiler implementation complexity) over the more standard (in other FP langs at least) reverse pipeline operator (which elm already implements).  Can anyone speak to this?  [Feel free to post directly to that thread as well or I will paste back the best answers if no one else does].

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/elm-discuss/Kt0MbDyRpO4

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the discussion you reference, I see Evan poses two challenges:

1. Show me some F# project that uses it
2. Find some credible F# programmer talking about why it is a good idea and what costs come with it (blog post or something).

I'd answer as follows:

1. The forward pipe-idiom is very common in F# programming, both for stylistic (we like it) and practical (it helps type inference) reasons. Just about any F# project you'll find will use it frequently. Certainly all of my open source projects use it (Unquote, FsEye, NL found [here](http://code.google.com/u/105074354266714820623/)). No doubt you'll find the same with all of the [Github located F# projects](https://github.com/fsharp) including the F# compiler source itself.
2. Brian, a developer on the F# compiler team at Microsoft, blogged about [Pipelining in F#](https://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/pipelining-in-f/) back in 2008, a still very interesting and relevant blog which relates F# pipes to POSIX pipes. In my own estimation, there is very little cost to implementing a pipe operator. In the F# compiler, this is certainly true in every sense (it's a one-line, inline function definition).

Answer (score 3):

The pipeline operator is actually incredibly simple - here is the standard definition

```
let inline (|>) a b = b a
```

Also, the `.` operator discussed in the thread is the reverse pipe operator in F# (`<|`) which enables you to eliminate some brackets.

I don't think adding pipeline operators would have a significant impact on complexity

Comment: Yea, I knew the implementation would be rather trivial but I don't think that is the cost Evan is worried about.  His compiler is already *very* slow and I think he's concerned with increased compilation time.

Comment: @johanatan - Really compile time should be minimal - all you would need to do is replace `expr1 |> expr2` with `expr2(expr1)`.  This should be easy

Comment: I haven't read the whole thread, but Haskell's `(.)` operator corresponds to `(<<)` in F#, not `<|`.

Comment: @Frank Yes, there was definitely confusion in that thread between the function composition and pipeline operators.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the excellent answers already given here, I'd like to add a couple more points.

Firstly, one of the reasons why the pipeline operator is common in F# is that it helps to circumvent a shortcoming the way type inference is currently done. Specifically, if you apply an aggregate operation with a lambda function that uses OOP to a collection type inference will typically fail. For example:

```
Seq.map (fun z -> z.Real) zs
```

This fails because F# does not yet know the type of `z` when it encounters the property `Real` so it refuses to compile this code. The idiomatic fix is to use the pipeline operator:

```
xs |> Seq.map (fun z -> z.Real)
```

This is strictly uglier (IMO) but it works.

Secondly, the F# pipe operator is nice to a point but you cannot currently get the inferred type of an intermediate result. For example:

```
x
|> h
|> g
|> f
```

If there is a type error at `f` then the programmer will want to know the type of the value being fed into `f` in case the problem was actually with `h` or `g` but this is not currently possible in Visual Studio. Ironically, this was easy in OCaml with the Tuareg mode for Emacs because you could get the inferred type of any subexpression, not just an identifier.